# How to Concatenate integers in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to concatenate two strings, year and Quarter, which are structured like so: 
Year|Q

2007|1

2008|2

2005|4

I have tried the following code:

```
   update  `Project.MACRO.Table`  
set YearQuarter =  CAST(year as string) + '_' + CAST(quarter as string) 
where quarter is not null
```

it does not work as only INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC are supported signatures. I don't believe I can use group_concat as part of an update. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CONCAT() function as below

```
CONCAT(CAST(year as STRING),'_',CAST(quarter as STRING))
```

or you can use FORMAT() as below

```
FORMAT('%i_%i', year, quarter)
```